# How to ensure process ended on remote machine using WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

This method which creates a process on remote machine using WMI

```
public void RunProcess(string processName, int timeoutInMinutes)
{
    ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
    ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
    ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(m_managementScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);

    ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
    inParams["CommandLine"] = processName;
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

    if (outParams != null)
    {
        string processID = outParams["processId"].ToString();
        WaitForProcessToFinish(processID, timeoutInMinutes);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("process was not created while tried to run it");
    }
}
```

While this method gets processID and should query if process with ID x ended. Since i cannot execute WQL using any WMI browser (since it is EventWatcher query). I need help to make it work.

```
private void WaitForProcessToFinish(string processID, int timeoutInMinutes)
{
    const string wmiPollingInSeconds = "10";

    string queryString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN {0} WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Handle={1}", wmiPollingInSeconds, processID);
    WqlEventQuery wql = new WqlEventQuery(queryString);
    ManagementEventWatcher watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher {Query = wql, Scope = m_managementScope};

    int currentTimeoutInminutes = 0;
    while (timeoutInMinutes > currentTimeoutInminutes)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject mbOobj = watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
        if ((((ManagementBaseObject)mbOobj["TargetInstance"])["ProcessID"].ToString() == processID))
        {
            break;
        }
        watcher.Stop();
        throw new Exception(string.Format("couldn't find process {0} to get it's events",processID));
    }
    watcher.Stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`__InstanceDeletionEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI event instead

```
string queryString = string.Format("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN {0} WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Handle={1}", wmiPollingInSeconds, processID);
```